# Running chown in bash script produces errors

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu, gnome, chown

I'm working on a script that downloads a file with `bar:bar` ownership, then changes the ownership to `foo:server`. So I wrote a side script(`chown_test.sh`) to implement the changing of the ownership via `chown`. Once working I'll inject it into the main script, but I've run into a problem (shown below) probably due to my lack of experience using `chown`.

**Note:** I tried to include all the necessary information below, but if you need more information just let me know via a comment.

**Directory structure, ownerships and permissions:**

```
+ drwxrwxr-x 2 foo:server chown_test  # test directory
├─  -rwxrwxr-- 1 foo:server chown_test.sh  # side script
├─  -rwxrwxr-- 1 bar:bar    file           # empty file
```

**Relevant entries from `/etc/group`:**

```
sudo:x:27:foo
bar:x:33:foo
foo:x:1000:
server:x:1003:bar,foo
```

**The `chown_test.sh` code:**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "User: $USER"
chown foo:server ./file
```

I've also tried `sudo chown foo:server ./file` but that prompts me to enter a sudo password for `bar`, which doesn't have a sudo password.

**Output of running `chown_test.sh` as `bar`:**

```
[16:13 foo@Opus]:~/chown_test$ sudo -H -u bar bash -c ./chown_test.sh
User: bar
chown: changing ownership of ‘./file’: Operation not permitted
```

**Output of running `chown_test.sh` as `foo`:**

```
[16:14 foo@Opus]:~/chown_test$ ./chown_test.sh 
User: foo
chown: changing ownership of ‘./file’: Operation not permitted
```

Could someone please shed some light on my dilemma?
Thank you for reading my question.

---

### Update:

With help from [Toby Speight's answer and comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/255415/53748), I arrived at a happy medium.

Since, *"Only a privileged process (Linux: one with the `CAP_CHOWN` capability) may change the owner of a file. The owner of a file may change the group of the file to any group of which that owner is a member."*, then I just decided to only change the group, not the owner.

I did this by changing the `chown` command in `chown_test.sh` to:

```
chown :server ./file
```

and the result:

```
├─  -rwxrwxr-- 1 bar:server file
```

Which is suitable for me, but if it's unsuitable for you then have a look at [Toby Speight's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/255415/53748) below for more information.

Comment: Add a tag for the operating system.  They do vary in the behaviour of `chown` - e.g. I know that HP/UX only allows root to change ownership, but Linux allows the owner to change the group (within limits - see the `chown(2)` man page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `chown(2)` man page:

> Only a privileged process (Linux: one with the `CAP_CHOWN` capability)
>   may change the owner of a file.  The owner of a file may change the
>   group of the file to any group of which that owner is a member.  A
>   privileged process (Linux: with `CAP_CHOWN`) may change the group
>          arbitrarily.

Your process is neither privileged, nor changing the group of a file it owns to a group the owner is in.

Therefore you will need to gain suitable privilege.  The two easiest ways to do so are

1. Write a minimal binary program (probably in C) to set the ownership of that file (I'm assuming that the file's pathname can be hard-coded, to prevent abuse) and make it set-user-id to root, or even better, add `CAP_CHOWN` capability with `sudo setcap cap_chown+ep <program_name>`, which won't make the program run as `root` with all of its consequences.
2. Write a suitable `/etc/sudoers` entry to permit that particular command to be executed using `sudo` without a password: write a line such as

   ```
   bar ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /bin/chown foo:server '/full/path/to/file'
   ```

   to a file in `/etc/sudoers.d` (and check that `/etc/sudoers` has a corresponding `#includedir` directive - most Linux distributions do).  Make sure the command called by your script matches exactly!

Comment: Thanks for answering. One question regarding *"... changing the group of a file it owns to a group the owner is in."* Would it be possible to use `chown` if I only change the group, not the owner, to `server`? Since `bar` is a member of the `server` group.

Comment: That's my reading of that statement - but it's worth confirming.  The target group might need to be in the process's supplementary list (i.e. those you see with the `id` command).

Comment: So I tried it out, without messing with the process' supplementary list, changing `foo:server` to just `:server` in `chown_test.sh` and running `sudo -H -u bar bash -c ./chown_test.sh` and it changed the ownership of `file` to `bar:server`. Which is acceptable and great. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @JonnyHenly I think that in the case of point 1, adding `CAP_CHOWN` capability might be preferred to setuid, to limit impact if program's somehow buggy.

Comment: @TNW How would I go about adding `CAP_CHOWN` capability? Would I just export `CAP_CHOWN` with some value in my `.bashrc`? I can Google how to do this, I just figured if anyone else reads these comments and is curious then they won't have to do a Google search.

Comment: Be advised that opening sudo as suggested will most likely open up the entire system unless the specific filename is very easy to whitelist, as sudo only protects from jumping up folders in the actual command and not in arguments

Comment: @JonnyHenly I've just edited the answer to include that information, should appear after passing the review.

Comment: @D.S - I've added a specific suggestion for a `sudoers` entry as an example.